# Start ActionMode() from Listadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, actionmode

i have a problem with a custom ListView-Adapter.
So I'm trying to start the ActionMode of ActionBarSherlock, when a Checkbox (Every Listitem has one) is checked. I implemented an OnClickListener directly in the adapter:

```
((CheckBox) holder.check_entry).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //code
    }
});
```

How can I start the ActionMode correctly?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the activity and call [`Activity#startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActionMode%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29). As parameter you need to pass an implementation of the [`ActionMode.Callback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html) interface. Check out the [ActionMode sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ActionModes.java) of ActionBarSherlock.

By the way, regarding the `ListView` with checkboxes, I would take a look at [`android:choiceMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3achoiceMode) and [`ListView#isItemChecked(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#isItemChecked%28int%29).

Comment: Do you mean by MainActivity reference = new MainActivity(); ? Thanks for your response

Comment: Edit: I have now: MainActivity.startActionMode(MainActivity.mActionModeCallback); But the callback needs to be static (public static ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback), but then some commands in the callback won't work because i cannot make the dbhelper-object static (depends on private db dbhelper = new db(this);)

Comment: If you have declared the adapter within the activity, you can just write `startActionMode(...)`. Why does the callback has to be static? Implement it just like it is done in the sample I linked to.

Comment: The problem is that the onclick-listener for a list-item is in the adapter itself, which makes everything a bit more complicated. If you can tell me how to port it to the MainActivity your solution should be no problem. I haven't found another way to listen to checkbox-changes, because I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: If you can't solve this yourself, I think creating a new question with code will be most useful.

Comment: I found a solution: I override the getView-Method of the custom adapter in my MainActivity.